# Can I use a tactile switch as computer power switch?

Tags: switches, cpu, computers, atx, motherboard

I was thinking of replacing my broken power button in my CPU with a tactile switch connected to the power cord on the motherboard, but I was wondering if that would work without any harmful consequences for the computer or me?[image]

Comment: In order for everybody to be on the exact same side, can you add an image to your question showing the button that is broken? It would be a shame if there was some misunderstanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my own atx power switch?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/how-to-make-my-own-atx-power-switch)

Comment: I prefer a screwdriver, but that's just me

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your PSU is an ATX one,

> PS-ON is an active low signal that turns on all of the main power rails including 3.3V, 5V, -5V, 12V, and -12V
>   power rails. When this signal is held high by the PC board or left open circuited, outputs of the power rails should
>   not deliver current and should be held at a zero potential with respect to ground. Power should be delivered to the
>   rails only if the PS-ON signal is held at ground potential. This signal should be held at +5VDC by a pull-up resistor
>   internal to the power supply.

Source: [ATX Specification - version 2.01](http://joule.bu.edu/~hazen/LinuxCluster/atx_201.pdf)

So if your PSU is indeed an ATX supply, PS-ON seems to be a high impedance input. In that case, and if the power switch is connected directly to your PSU, then there shouldn't be a problem pulling it to GND using a tactile switch.

However, the power switch might be going through some logic or buffering on your motherboard, so you might want to look up the specifications for your motherboard if you want to make sure it's safe. I suspect it will be safe, but without knowing your motherboard there's no sure way to tell.

See also:

- [Using PWR_OK to Activate an ATX Power Supply Automatically](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91606/using-pwr-ok-to-activate-an-atx-power-supply-automatically)
- [Does an ATX PSU's PS_ON Signal Require Resistance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97306/does-an-atx-psus-ps-on-signal-require-resistance)

Comment: But: How large is that pull-up, or, conversely, how high's the current through the button?

Comment: A pertinent question. Although I've now added a paragraph about the motherboard, which might make the question slightly less relevant in practice.

Comment: yeah, true, I saw that. Got out my motherboard's manual – doesn't specify the current, either.

Comment: But let's say a "pull-up" would be > 500Ω, that feels like a safe assumption. Then the current would be < 5V/500Ω = 10 mA.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the maximum current that you might need to switch would be low enough that it's safe to switch that current with such a microswitch.

More info can be found in the datasheet of your switch of choice.

Comment: then what type of switch would you recommend?

Comment: You could use that switch to control a relay though.

Comment: I didn't say it *wouldn't* work, but you should make sure that the swtich you're buying is rated for the current you switch

Comment: are you talking about the button on the front of the computer or the back of the computer?

Comment: @HarrySvensson do you mean me or Alpha G? I refer to the front-panel button, which usually just switches a standby voltage, and I'm frantically trying to find a standards document that says "current is limited to x mA", but having no luck. Thus, I'd go with "if your switch can switch >=500mA, you're probably fine". Now, over time, I've bought a lot of different switches, some of which are rated for only 2mA, others for 2A in similar form factors (but not as similar prices).

Comment: If I would've wanted to talk to Alpha I would've commented on his question. Which I did where I asked him to add an image so your answer matches his question. - As far as I know the one in the back should be for a couple of amps, and the one in the front could be a couple of milliAmps.

Comment: @HarrySvensson :)  Anyway, yeah, that's a bit of the point: OP's photo is not saying what current that switch is rated for. I have a few very similarly looking ones that are only spec'ed for 2mA. And "a couple of mA" is > 2mA...